# 100% component based Angular/Ionic app development

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have 2 child components as shown below.

*Child component 1:*

[image]

*Child component 2:*

[image]

You can see that its styles, position, and etc are the same. But the content is different. i.e. image and text. So I would like to develop a 100% component based Ionic/Angular app. My question here is do I need to use 2 components here or use the same component with `*ngIf` with  `@Input()` bindings to determine the different text and image according to the parent page?

e.g. Is this fine or do I need to have 2 complete components for these kinds of use cases? Here it seems tightly coupled with a parent. i.e. changing something will require a lot of work due to the breaking of other places and etc.  Am I wrong here?

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center padding-bottom-0">
      <h5 class="font-bold margin-top-bottom-5">{{'Client.Parcel-Delivery-Cost' | translate}}</h5>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="12" class="padding-top-bottom-0 ion-text-center" *ngIf="isPickUp">
      <div>{{'Client.Parcel-Picked-Up-From-The-Location-And-Delivered-To-You' | translate}}</div>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="12" class="padding-top-bottom-0 ion-text-center" *ngIf="!isPickUp">
      <div>{{'Client.Parcel-Picked-Up-And-Handed-Over-To-Respective-Courier' | translate}}</div>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size="12" class="padding-top-bottom-0 ion-text-center font-bold">
      <h4 class="margin-top-5 font-bold"> {{parcelDeliveryCost}}</h4>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: I'd pass client object as @Input and reuse. btw, is [Parcel-Delivery-Cost] a field name of Client object.. ?

Comment: @ihorbond It is a property of Child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you just need one component, a dumb Component.
Lets name it StepComponent

```
export class StepComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() details: DetailData;

constructor(){}
ngOnInit(){}

}
```

Then in the template, you should access the `details` property and render the data. The `DetailData` type is just a model to hold all the details properties (e.g name, description, image).

```
<h4>{{details.name}}</h4>
<p{{details.description}}</p>
```

There's also a different technique that can be useful to reuse some logic but render something different if required. It is called content projection and it's nicely explained here:
https://www.prestonlamb.com/blog/content-projection-in-angular

Comment: I think your approach is the best since I don't need to use `*ngIf` here. i.e. it is fully dynamic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

angular is a component-based framework. so usually when you can avoid rewriting codes you better do it. especially in this case. they have exactly the same layout.